# React does not recognize the `InputProps` prop on a DOM element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

[image: Error stacktrace screenshot]

Warning: React does not recognize the `InputProps` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `inputprops` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.

***I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. And I've seen many similar issues like this. But I couldn't see a proper solution.***

```
<TextField
  {...input}
  {...rest}
  name={input.name}
  inputRef={inputRef}
  autoFocus={inputRef.current === document.activeElement}
  disabled={disabled || false}
  multiline={rowCount ? true : false}
  style={{
    width: "100%",
  }}
  onChange={(event) => {
    input.onChange(event.target.value);
  }}
  {...(hesapla
    ? {
        onBlur: (e) => {
          hesapla({ name: input.name, value: input.value });
        },
        onKeyDown: (e) => {
          if (e.key === "Enter") {
            hesapla({ name: input.name, value: input.value });
            e.preventDefault();
          }
        },
      }
    : {})}
  InputProps={{
    classes,
    ...(inputComponent ? { inputComponent: inputComponent } : {}),
    ...(endAdornment ? { endAdornment: endAdornment } : {}),
  }}
  inputProps={{
    style: {
      maxHeight: (rowCount * 16).toString() + "px",
      overflow: "auto",
      ...(rightJustify ? { textAlign: "end" } : {}),
      ...(!readOnly && hesapla
        ? { fontWeight: "bold", borderBottom: "2px solid" }
        : {}),
    },
    readOnly: readOnly ? readOnly : false,
  }}
></TextField>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: It uses InputProps in its Material UI TextField instances. And I use it in my own code following the same path.

Comment: Which MUI do you have?

Comment: "@material-ui/core": "4.11.0",
    "@material-ui/data-grid": "^4.0.0-alpha.20",
    "@material-ui/docs": "4.0.0-beta.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "4.9.1",
    "@material-ui/lab": "4.0.0-alpha.56",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "3.2.10",
    "@material-ui/styles": "4.10.0",
    "@material-ui/system": "4.9.14",

Answer (score 5):

the issue is that you are using `inputProps` instead of `InputProps`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with your `InputProps` object, according to the documentation, it uses an `object`, you didn't pass a proper object to it.

So, if you want to realize this issue, I suggest you create your `InputProps` entry as a variable and log it:

```
const myInputPropsObject = {
    classes,
    ...(inputComponent ? { inputComponent: inputComponent } : {}),
    ...(endAdornment ? { endAdornment: endAdornment } : {}),
  }

console.log(myInputPropsObject)
```

**Note:** destruction of an empty object will cause the `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token` issue.

to check it:

```
const myObject = {
  name: 'testName',
  ...{},
}
```

Comment: ...(inputComponent ?? { inputComponent: inputComponent }), ...(endAdornment ?? { endAdornment: endAdornment }), 
@nima
 When I write the code as above, there is no error in the console. And it works fine. But I don't really understand what it means, what does it have to do with my problem. Anyway, I think my problem is solved. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: take a look at your implementaion, for example, if `inputComponent` be `false` the `{}` will return, now take a look at **Note**, similar to `endAdornment` @MüminZEHİR

Answer (score 3):

Those who came to this post and using MUI Autocomplete, the culprit is your input element. Autocomplete widget by default expects you to use Textfield Input as of now. (the params passed to the input element are only available on Textfield widget, see image below).

**TextField**
[image: Textfield Input Component]

**Input Base**
[image: InputBase Input component]

If you want to use any other input field, extract the props from the params passed and pass the desired props to your input element. Like, i used InputBase component and passed only **inputProps** not **InputProps** to it. You can find the available properties in MUI documentation.